# Solr Json Put Json Document using Curl

Tags: json, curl, solr

I amtrying to Put a json document in solr core using

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://xxxx:6083/solr/daw_index/update?commit=true' -d'
{
"add":{
"doc":{
  "dataSet_s": "ORACLE",
  "ruleType_s": "IF_EQUALS_THEN_EQUALS",
  "enable_s": "true",
  "testCaseId_s": "CASE_2",
  "condition": {
    "conClause": "ESLEE",
    "conField": "ENGINE_RPM",
    "conOperator1": "GREATER",
    "conVal1": "5000",
    "conVal2": ""
  }
}
}
}
```

'

Only the first four fields are added in core as document

```
{
        "dataSet_s": "ORACLE",
        "ruleType_s": "IF_EQUALS_THEN_EQUALS",
        "enable_s": "true",
        "testCaseId_s": "CASE_2",
        "id": "9da24b8f-5766-4b72-b47b-4fea52490563",
        "_version_": 1541169726491721700
      }
```

I need to add entire doc with condition object.
Also how can we add array of json Objects in solr

Comment: What kind of schema are you using?

Comment: No Schema , I have just created a core..using create -c core_name

Answer (score 0):

You are using Solr Update JSON format, but not specifying child documents correctly. They need to be [object structures within an array mapped to a key called ***childDocuments***](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments).

And you do always have a schema. If you run

```
bin/solr create_core -h
```

You will see more explanation of what is actually happening, including the name of the configuration you bootstrap from if you don't specify one explicitly (data_driven_schema_configs in Solr 6.1).

You can see your live configuration the Admin UI's **Files** screen. Look for *managed-schema* file for the schema file. In your case, it specifies dynamic fields using suffixes to assign the correct type, [one of which is *_s](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.1.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/managed-schema#L135) and the reason your posting worked. If you get the child records to work where fields do not have extensions to match the dynamic field definitions, you will instead trigger the "schemaless" mode that will guess the files based on rules specified in solrconfig.xml and will add those to the schema explicitly. That will trigger recreation of the *managed-schema* file (dynamic fields do not).